# Node.js Crawler Error

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, npm

I'm on Mac OSX and I've been trying to use Node.js with Crawler. Now i've just installed following steps as it instructed:

- `git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git`
- `cd node`
- `./configure`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`
- `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`
- `npm install crawler`

As soon as i've installed the last one (Crawler), when i test run the `test/simple.js` as in its sample, i'm getting following errors:

```
The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.
http://jamendo.com/
http://tedxparis.com

/crawler/node_modules/crawler/lib/crawler.js:74
                        response.body = body;
                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'body' of undefined
    at Object.callback (/crawler/node_modules/crawler/lib/crawler.js:74:39)
    at Request._callback (/crawler/node_modules/crawler/lib/crawler.js:70:43)
    at /crawler/node_modules/crawler/node_modules/request/main.js:119:22
    at Request.<anonymous> (native)
    at Request.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Object._onTimeout (/crawler/node_modules/crawler/node_modules/request/main.js:532:12)
    at Timer.ontimeout (timers.js:84:39)
```

This means the `Crawler` doesn't work yet. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- Try a newer version of Crawler
- Use an older version of Node
- Use a different module **(recommended, as Crawler is very out of date)**
- Fix Crawler yourself (and submit your patches!, but it seems nobody is maintaining this project anymore)

If this is just a one-time error, you can wrap the whole thing in a try/catch and handle it as needed.

Comment: Sorry? `Crawler is very out of date` ??

Comment: Yes, it hasn't been updated in more than a year, which is a very long time when it comes to Node.js.

Answer (score -1):

You may also be interested in trying my Node Crawler (https://github.com/ecdeveloper/node-web-crawler). It's not a module but an independent web app. It uses Mongo, Express, Socket.io, Twitter bootstrap.